# MySQL-python - mysql_config not found

Tags: python, mysql, cygwin, mysql-python

I am trying to install MySQLDB/MySQL-python on Cygwin with a Windows MySQL server. While installing it errs out with the error below.

Is there a way to work around the below 2 issues. I dont want to install MySQLDB on cygwin. I only want the connector to use in the code.

```
$ pip install MySQL-python
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python
EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

pip install MySQLdb
Downloading/unpacking MySQLdb
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement MySQLdb
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it fixed after installing "libmysqlclient-devel"

```
apt-cyg install libmysqlclient-devel
```

Still MySQLdb does not work with sock file error. Opened another thread for that problem

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what os you are using but ive found some windows mysqldb libs if that's what you want they have versions for python 2.5-2.7

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python

Hope this helps